# Associativity of functions in scala

Tags: scala

What does it mean when someone says "**functions in scala associate to the right**"?

And, how will associativity work in case `Int => Int => Int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function type `Int => Int => Int` is equivalent to `Int => (Int => Int)`.  In other words, the `=>` groups things on the right first, or, is right-associative.

The type `Int => (Int => Int)` defines a single-argument function that accepts an `Int` and whose return-type is function from `Int` to `Int`.

So what's an example of such a function?  We could write a function called `sum` with this type:

```
val sum: Int => Int => Int = {
  (a: Int) =>
    {
      (b: Int) =>
        a + b
    }
}
```

So `sum` takes an argument `a` and returns a new function that accepts and argument `b` and returns the sum of `a` and `b`:

```
scala> val sumWith3 = sum(3)         // `sum` takes an Int argument
sumWith3: Int => Int = <function1>   // notice the return type of `Int => Int`

scala> sumWith3(5)                   // takes an Int argument
res0: Int = 8                        // returned an Int
```

Comment: Can I write val sum: Int => Int => Int as val sum: (a: Int) (b: Int): Int ?